# How can I restore the network connection to my Epson XP-200

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, printer, network-printer, epson-workforce

I have an Epson XP-200 and a mac laptop. I got a new wifi and when I went to print something my printer wouldn't connect to wifi and kept flashing orange (on the wifi button.) I tried deleting the Epson from my computer and reinstalling it but now my computer can't locate the printer and I don't know the IP address either. How can I connect my printer back to wifi and back to my laptop? Thank you so much any responses would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Even without the manual, the answer is likely on the internet.

According to this [web page provided by Epson](https://epson.com/faq/SPT_C11CC48201~faq-219946), you can press the WPS button on the router and then hold the wifi button on your printer for 3 seconds.

Pressing the WPS button on your router opens up the device for "approved" connections of devices in range. When you press the wifi button on your printer for 3 seconds, it tells your router that it is an approved device and should then make the connection necessary to have your computer software locate your printer and continue normally.

It may be necessary to connect your printer to your computer with a USB cable in order to configure the wireless settings of the printer. This would be a temporary arrangement and the instructions should be provided during the software installation, if the WPS button method does not work.

You will need to know the SSID and key for your wireless network for the second method to work properly.